# .htaccess rewrite rule to remove index.html inbetween the url

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

In my application, I will be redirect from a website to open an url link as below:

```
https://[site]/index.html#/Login
```

In that url site I'm using AnuglarJS, now i need to redirect like 'https://[site]/#/Login' but I didn't work. How I should write .htaccess to remove index.html from the URL. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but this is not possible with `.htaccess` or any other server side solution.
The reason is very simple. A basic URL is build like this:

```
scheme://host/path?query#fragment
```

So in your case this

```
scheme   => https
host     => site
path     => index.html
query    => N/A
fragment => /Login
```

The point is, that the fragment is nothing a browser ever sends to the server. So in your case, from the server point of view you have requested:

```
https://[site]/index.html
```

The server can redirect or rewrite it to `https://[site]/` but not to `https://[site]/#Login`, at least not if you want to use different kinds of
fragments like `#/Login`, `#/Logout`, `#/SomePage`, etc. what I assume.

You have to do this on the browser site, in your case with AnuglarJS.